# laravel 5.3 working with cookies in all application

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.3

Im making a multicountry app. I want the user to change the country so i create links like this:

```
Route::get('/pais/{code}', ['as' => 'pais', 'uses' => 'HomeController@pais']);
```

The cookie should work on all the app to avoid selecting country again.
And this is the controller:

```
public function pais($code){
    if(validarPais($code)){
        cookie('pais', strtoupper($code),999999);
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Now i need to access in every page to that cookie. How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: The [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#cookies) tell you how to access the cookie: `$pais = $request->cookie('pais');`

Comment: I use that, the cookie is null

Comment: Then the cookie wasn't set properly; either because $code was empty or failed validation. Why don't you set it as described in the docs I linked

Comment: For example if i change the return to return the cookie:
return cookie('pais', strtoupper($code),999999);
it works:
pais=BO; expires=Tue, 21-Aug-2018 06:50:26 GMT; path=/; httponly

But i can't access in blade to that cookie

Comment: What does `validarPais()` do? Is it successfully validating `$code`? And again, why aren't you setting the cookie as shown in the documentation, linking it to the response?

Comment: Only check if is a valid country, yes is working fine. Because i want the cookie to be available to all app not only for the next response, i want something like a global variable that last on browser exit. thanks.

Comment: Returning a cookie doesn't simply make it available for just the next request. A cookie is set in the browser and sent with ___every___ subsequent request. That's how cookies work

Comment: Thanks man it works! I think the cookie was saved on controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel sessions:

```
Session::set('pais', strtoupper($code));
```

And then get value:

```
Session::get('pais');
```

You can access these variables as long as user is logged into your application

Comment: Thanks, but i want to store the country in that computer